# Technique that allows a website to perform numerous simultaneous computations

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I am developing a website which basically does the following:

1. User can enter some input, typically numbers.
2. By clicking on a button, the website applies some algorithm to the input. This algorithm is (a little bit) computationally intensive.
3. The result of the algorithm should then be shown on the website to the user.

**Question:** How does one code this kind of workflow most efficiently - it is very important for me that...

- ... the computations are performed as fast as possible so that the user gets the result as fast as possible.
- ... the web site can be accessed by a lot of people at the same time without slowing each others computations down.

**My own initial approach:** I have done some research, but I didn't find *the* ideal solution. One option I encountered was to simply do everything in JavaScript on the website, however I found that JavaScript is slow which doesn't satisfy my needs. I describe my current approach in the following - **if this approach is not the best one please correct me and then there is no need to spend time on my approach - suggesting a better approach is far more useful for me**. My current approach can be described as follows:

a.) After the user enters some input and clicks the button, the input data gets uploaded into a file on the server. This file should then be in the same folder as the .html file for the web site. **Example:** A user can enter a number and the website doubles the number for the user (a toy example of course). The multiply.html code:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    Enter a number: <input type="text" id="numberField">
    <button type="button" id="doubleButton">Double!</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Note:** By clicking the button, the entered number should written to a file "input.txt", however this functionality is missing since I didn't figure out how to do it...

b.) We assume that the user input is now stored in a file "input.txt". Then, my idea is to run a program that reads "input.txt", does the actual calculations and writes the result into a file "output.txt". **Example Continued:** The "input.txt" file contains a single number "5" and nothing else. There is a C-program in the same folder that does the actual computation - in this case doubling the value of "5". So there is a source file "program.c" with code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE * fp;
    int inputNumber;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r"); 
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &inputNumber);
    FILE *f = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fprintf(f, "%d", 2*inputNumber);
    fclose(f);
    fclose(fp);
    }
```

c.) In a third and last step, the content of the "output.txt" file - in the example it is "10" - gets uploaded and is shown somehow on the website.

**To summarize**, there are two issues I have:

1. What is the best technique to achieve to achieve a.),b.) and c.) such that the website is responding quickly and can be accessed by numerous users simultaneously?
2. If my own initial approach is the best technique, how can I get it running? Meaning that hitting the button on the website downloads the data, executes the .c program, uploads the output data and displays it on the website?

I know that is a lot of content for one question - I hope I could make my points clear. Thank you for every help and comment!

Comment: Barebone Javascript is not allowed to write to an arbitrary file the filesytem. You could look into Java applets, although they are losing popularity. Alternatively you let a powerful server do it, but then it should be powerful enough to deal with concurrent access and still provide timely results.

Comment: By "*input data gets downloaded into a file*" I'll assume you meant "input data gets uploaded into a file on the server"?

Comment: You will want to read about [CGI scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) which is essentially the approach you describe. However, that approach is quite outdated, today you'd rather write the whole server in the language of your choice with a popular framework for max scalability (which in your case means many concurrent computations for many users).

Comment: Without knowing what the algorithm is or what exactly you mean by "*(a little bit) computationally intensive*" we can't really suggest you an optimal approach. Your assessment that clientside js is too slow for the task might not be very accurate, maybe you just tried to do the wrong thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! 
@ Bergi: Yes, I meant "input data gets uploaded into a file on the server". Thank you for the reference and also for the hint that this approach is nowadays rather outdated. Could you please go into more details with "today you'd rather write the whole server in the language of your choice with a popular framework for max scalability (which in your case means many concurrent computations for many users)" - some references would be great.

Comment: @ Bergi: By "(a little bit) computationally intensive" I mean that the website should be able to perform the following task in about a second: The input the user enters is a matrix of dimension of about 15 times 15. Consider the matrix as the cost matrix of the TSP problem. The algorithm then solves the TSP optimally (so I use an exact algorithm). In addition, the algorithm should also store intermediate steps in form of, let's say, a plot.

Comment: @ trincot: I don't want to use an approach that is losing popularity, so I take into consideration your suggested option - to let it do a powerful server. Can you give me some more information on how to settle this up, e.g. some references? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically, what you want to do, is make a normal form-based server interaction and run some code on the server before returning the result. Alternatively, if you want to run this asynchronously, you just want to provide an API on the server that performs the computation for a given input which you call from the client. Both are standard scenarios for which you should find lots of examples.

Comment: When you say that "JavaScript is slow which doesn't satisfy my needs" is that because you actually implemented your algorithm in JavaScript and found that it doesn't execute as fast as you want? Or are you assuming it will be too slow because of things you read? Did you try using http://mathjs.org/?

Comment: @PeterHaight I assumed that JavaScript will be too slow because of the things I read. However, I haven't used mathjs.org - so I am now going to implement the algorithm with mathjs.org and see how it works. Thanks for this hint!